# Float not working in CSS

Tags: css, blogger

I've inline CSS like this. But the float is not working.

```
<div style='clear:both'>
    <div style='display:block;float:right;margin:10px;width:200px'>
        <img src = 'http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png' height='200px' width='200px'/>          
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested code in this page - http://test-knowafest.blogspot.in/2013/03/fuseout-2013-government-engineering.html

You can see the image next to post title. The image is not getting floated. I tried several combinations of paramaters in style, but it is not working. Can you anyone tell me where I went wrong.

It looks like below now

[image]

====================================

## **But I want it like below.**

[image]

Comment: how can you assume the float is not working? Where do you want to align the image? what is you desired output?

Comment: Using inline styles probably is something where you went wrong. And why not just float the image instead of the div?

Comment: I assume you want text on left and the image on right, for instance text `float:left;` and `image float:right;`. Both wrapping with each other. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AnaMaria, I want the text to be seen left to the the image. I want the text to be wrapped around image. I want the image to be aligned right. I think, that is what my code does. Like, there is some text after this div and that text should be wrapped around this image. You can take a look at the page link I gave above. The image is below the post title. Please let me know if I'm clear.

Comment: @NathanLee, exactly. I tried that as well. But it did not work.

Comment: @Tdelang, actually I want to float an ad there which is rendered by javascript. Before that, I'm trying to a simple image there. Even though image works, it is not useful. So, I want to float the div. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Make a little picture of what you're expecting. It will be much easier to assist.

Comment: It works. DIV with image is floated right. Parent div is full block size, but no content so displays nothing around floated div.

Comment: @CoryDanielson, I added pics in description. Kindly check. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I suggest your html code is wrong so that if you change your html code that is possible

Comment: @RohitAzad, can you please explain. I couldn't get what is wrong.

Comment: @TechCrunch, check the solution by nathan lee

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963539/float-not-working-in-css/17963710#17963710) - @TechCrunch

Comment: @Saram, I have code like below.  
<div style='clear: both; overflow: hidden; display: inline; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;'>
<div style='float:right;margin:10px;width:200px'>
<img src = 'http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png' height='200px' width='200px'/>                          </div>                 <data:post.body/>
</div> - data post body gives the text.

Comment: @NathanLee Thank you so much for the help. Can you please check the expected output I posted in description. Your solution doesn't put any text below the image. Is there a possibility that other CSS in the page is overriding this ? I can only that inline CSS has first preference.

Comment: The page content do not match what you described. There content is not inserted in place where `<data:post.body>` is. 
Nevertheless I posted working solution based on page content.

Comment: you are messing your design to more deep by using inline styling. why don't you add classes to those elements?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/FVg4G/)**

**The Code:**

```
<div id="post-body-3682190942132900250" class="post-body entry-content">
    <div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; display: inline; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;">
        <div style="float:right;margin:10px;width:200px">
            <img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <!-- The New Addition is here -->
        <div trbidi="on" style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr">
            <div style="clear: both; text-align: center;" class="separator"></div>
<span id="fullpost"> This information is brought to you by <a target="_blank" href="http://knowafest.com/">www.knowafest.com</a>  </span>
            <br>
            <hr>
<span id="fullpost"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Event:</span> Fuseout 2013 | Technical Fest
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 is Organised by:</span>  <a href="http://www.knowafest.com/search/label/Government%20Engineering%20College">Government Engineering College</a>, <a href="http://www.knowafest.com/search/label/Trivandrum">Trivandrum</a>, <a href="http://www.knowafest.com/search/label/Kerala">Kerala</a>
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 dates:</span> 
            <br>Fest dates: 15th-17th March 2013
            <br>Last Dates for Registration: Spot Registrations Open
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;"> Details:</span>
            <br>Fuseout Is A Technical Fest Organised By The Electrical And Electronics Department Students Of Govt Engineering College Barton Hill ,Trivandrum As Part Of AAGNEYA'13 Aiming To Bring Together The Intellectual Minds Of Our Country In A Competition Like None Other.
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Technical Events in Trivandrum :</span>
            <br>Robotron
            <br>Circuito Metego
            <br>Scrap Maniac
            <br>Wire-In
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Co-ordinators Details:</span><span style="color: green;"><br>Leo K A<br>9995992755</span>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">How to reach Government Engineering College: </span>
            <br>At Kanakakunnu Palace Grounds
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Website: </span><a target="_blank" href="http://tinyurl.com/fuseout2">http://tinyurl.com/fuseout2</a>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Facebook Link: </span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/fuseout.aagneya"><img src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/icons/facebook.gif"></a>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Youtube Link: </span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TP4igb1dMdk"><img src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/icons/youtube.gif"></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Fuseout 2013 Event Departments: </span>CSE, ECE, IT, EEE, Instrumentation, Mechanical, Energy, Arts</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this serves your purpose.

Comment: I just formatted the code. (for readability) Sorry, If my change offended you. I hope I didn't change anything...

Comment: No offends. Just was willing to know the reason for the change. I got my answer :) - @Mr_Green

Comment: Hi @NathanLee, actually I'm trying to include this image inside a blog post. I saw this solution in several blogs. I'm not finding a reason as to why its not working. They use only div style='float:right;' at all places. But it worked for them.

Comment: @AnaMaria unfortunately that did not work as well. Some other CSS element is messing up with this.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? My solution is the same that you wanna go with. Use my fiddle as the backbone and design your div.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with `clear: both` following you floating content:

```
<div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; display: inline; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;">
<div style="float:right;margin:10px;width:200px">
<img height="200px" src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png" width="200px">
</div>
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
</div>
```

Please remove it to get it worked as you wish (I hope).

```
<div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; display: inline; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;">
<div style="float:right;margin:10px;width:200px">
<img height="200px" src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png" width="200px">
</div>
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div class="separator" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**Maybe this is something that you want.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/FVg4G/1/)

You need to use the **float:right** style only on you image. Also check where you used the **clear:both** styling. That will mess with the alignment too.

```
<img src="http://knowafest.co.in/images/logo.png" width="95" height="84" style="float:right" /> <span id="fullpost">
```

Comment: This is how I wish it to look like. But some other CSS element is messing up I think. It is still not working after using like this.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? My solution is the same that you wanna go with. Use my fiddle as the backbone and design your div.

Comment: @TechCrunch as I noticed in my answer - you have `clear: both` following your `float: left` element. This is in `<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">`. Remove it!